# Android: NullPointerException (@ResolverActivity$ResolveListAdapter:fe_filterIntents:432) {main}

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I found reported exception from Google Analytics in my application. The only information for this exception is:

> NullPointerException (@ResolverActivity$ResolveListAdapter:fe_filterIntents:432) {main}

No stacktrace provided and other few things shown in the crash report is:

> Android version: 4.1.1, Mobile Device: Samsung Galaxy Nexus, Input type: touchscreen, Screen Resolution: 480x800

Is anybody knows how to solve this problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: take a look at the line mentioned in the error message

Comment: I have found the same error same phone, same Android version.  My error occurs when I try to use Intent.createChooser() to send an email message from the app.  I haven't found any solution.